# How activate Offlines files windows server 2008 r2 to use with IIS Shared Configuration?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, offline-files

I need to activate the Offline Files on my web server. This solution is for solve trouble with IIS shared configuration. There is the reason why I need to activate the Offline files.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/212/offline-files-for-shared-configuration/

I try to activate Offlines files on windows 2008 r2 but i am not able to do it.

Some body know why ?

I try this link 
http://www.win2008workstation.com/win2008/enable-offline-files-feature

this one 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755136.aspx

this one ...

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/212/offline-files-for-shared-configuration/

I cannot see offline files in my control panel. Why ?

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed the Desktop Experience role on your server?  "Offline Files" won't show up in the control panel until you do, and reboot.

Comment: Thanks  HopelessN00b, you can post the answer. It was the Desktop Experience role missing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Desktop Experience Role in order for the Offline Files to show up in the Control Panel. :)